# Autocomplete|Typehead for Delimited String

Tags: user-interface, typeahead

I'm trying to come up with a way to approach typehead in such a way that uniq substrings are given priority. For example, lets say I have the following:

```
foo.bar
foo.bar.baz
foo.bar.biz
foo.bar.bat
foo.bar.bat.art
foo.bar.bat.zap
...
foo.dog.alt
foo.dog.rar
...
foo.zed
foo.zed.rarg
```

Due to the drill down nature of the data, as the users types, the best thing to see what be the next unique option (since the list below the typeahead box would limited in length). So for example if someone where too type foo, they would see foo.bar, .foo.dog.alt, and foo.zed.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?